# Assigning TXT File to a Variable

Tags: java

Lets say I have a txt file that looks like:

```
2  3  4  5
6  7  8  9
1  2  3  4
3  4  5  8
8  6  5  8
1  0  3  8
```

I want to be able to create an ever growing set (the numbers provided are just a small sample of a bigger file) that will allow me to call upon the numbers in the set I create.

So lets say I want all variables that equal 8.  How can I make it so that I make my program read the text file, and then make it so that the program returns every 8 in the set?

I have heard of buffered readers and scanners, however; the scanner class takes a long time to read the file I have and the buffered reader is not an option for this problem because I need to be able to access past numbers as well.

Comment: "Can I" questions are most easily answered by [trying](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @CarrieKendall  loved this :)

Comment: You can do anything you want. Who is stopping you?

Comment: The OP appears to have tried something, for sure. As a non-Java person, he seems to be looking for a *file pointer*. I don't know if the equivalent in Java is named the same. Everyone, please try giving constructive, non-snarky comments. If you truly believe the OP hasn't put in enough effort, perhaps give a hint and teach them how to self-learn - but right now no answers whatsoever here actually help address the question. OP, my advice is to try googling file pointers, which are a way to indicate a position inside a file.

Comment: Yours was not the most snarky, @CarrieKendall, and your link tried to teach him something. Still, no-one at all actually tried to help. That's bad. You can read a 'can I' several ways, and since the OP has obviously already tried one approach or connected it to knowledge they already have, they are genuinely seeking more. It's ok to ask 'can I' if you don't know if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this using a 2-D array.
Any value can be fetched by providing column and rows index.